# Problem of the traveler in the desert, greedy and dynamic approach

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinations, dynamic-programming, greedy

A traveler in a desert wants to go from one oasis to another until a final destination without taking the risk of dying from thirst (i.e. lack of water). He know the position of all the oases from his starting point to his final destination. The traveler needs to drink one liter of wa for each kilometer made. When he leaves his starting point, he has a bottle full of water. When he reaches an oasis,he has two possibilites :

1 - continue his trip
2 - stop and refill his bottle of water to the max

each oasis, the traveler has to pay (say in euros) to a watchmen the quantity of water lost in each oasis. More precisely, he has to pay an amount equivalent to the squared of the number of liters of water emptied form the bottle when he stops and refills his bottle. We also to take into account the quantity of water emptied at the final destination. The problem now is then to find a solution in order to pay the minimum amount of money

a) Propose a greedy approach. Is it optimal ?

We propose to build a solution based on the dynamic programming paradigm. Your solution must consider the following quantities (note accessible points depend on the value of C)

- paid(i) : minimum amount of money paid from the starting point to point i when the traveler empties his bottle at point i - This the wuantity we want to optimize
- d(i,j) : number of kilometers between point i and point j
- C : the capacity of the bottle

Qustions :
1 - Give the structure of an optimal solution (and if possible prove its optimality)
2 - Give a recursive definition of the optimal value paid
3 - Provide an algorithme for finding the solution in polynomial time. You must provide a complete pseudo-code for all solution. Give the complexity (time and space)
4 - Provide an approach for computing the solution (i.e the trip)
5 - Apply yout algorithme to the following example : the bottle has a capacity of 10 liters, and source points located at 8, 9, 16, 18, 24, 27 kilometers from starting point and such that the final point is at 32 kilometers from the starting point

i would like to do a greedy algorithm and a dynamic algorithm, and i can't. I first tried to do the greedy approach

```py
def _cost(lastStop, d, Cmax, i) :
    
    if i == len(d)-1 :
        return (d[i]-lastStop)**2
    
    current = d[i]
    next = d[i+1]
    price = (Cmax-(lastStop-current))**2

    #We have water left
    if (next-lastStop) >= 0 :
        return min(_cost(lastStop, d, Cmax, i+1), _cost(current, d, Cmax, i+1) + price)
    #We don't have enough water we have to stop and refuel
    else :
        return _cost(current, d, Cmax, i+1) + price
   
def cost(d, Cmax) :

    return _cost(d[0],d,Cmax,0)


d = [8, 9, 16, 18, 24, 27, 32]
Cmax = 10

print(cost(d,Cmax))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250213/discussion-on-question-by-moudjahed-mohamed-problem-of-the-traveler-in-the-deser).

Comment: Just for clarification - at each oasis, if the traveller refills the bottle, he has to waste what is still in the bottle? For example, if the bottle has a capacity of 7 and contains 3 liters still, refilling means wasting 3 liters at a cost of 3^2=9 and then refill the bottle to contain 7 liters?

Comment: Just rough handwaving so far; one could try a state space as follows; C(i,j):=minimum cost to reach point i and have j liters in the bottle if such a cost exists, infinity otherwise.

Comment: No, he must not waste what remains in the bottle, if the bottle has a capacity of 7 and there are 3 liters, what you will have to pay is (7-3) ²

I did not understand your second message well, do you speak for the Greedy or Dynamic approach? You can develop a little more through a pseudo code perhaps, how a cost can not exist and that you can say by saying "infinite". If it is a matrix that must be completed it would be through which process that each value of the matrix would be filled by reusing values already calculated?

Comment: I will try to implement this your approach although it is ambiguous to me

Comment: It's been a while since I try to make the recursive approach that I put on the topic without success have been properly working.